# How to avoid nothing with Linq Query?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I would like make query with Linq on list of object. In some cases, I ve the following error :

```
The sequence contains no elements.
```

My Linq query :

```
MyList.Where(Function(s) Month(s.Histo_Date) = Month(Date_Reference) - 1 And Year(s.Histo_Date) = Year(Date_Reference)).Average(Function(s) s.Nb_Doc)
```

After few search I added this : DefaultIfEmpty()

```
MyList.Where(Function(s) Month(s.Histo_Date) = Month(Date_Reference) - 1 And Year(s.Histo_Date) = Year(Date_Reference)).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(s) s.Nb_Doc)
```

Now I've the following error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

How to avoid Nothing with Linq query ? I like to set the result of Linq query to 0 or String empty if is Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` has overload which takes "default" value.
Then by adding `Select` before `DefaultIfEmpty` you don't need to check for null or create "empty" instance of `s`

```vb
Dim avg = MyList.Where(Function(s) Month(s.Histo_Date) = Month(Date_Reference) - 1 AndAlso Year(s.Histo_Date) = Year(Date_Reference)).
                 Select(Function(s) s.Nb_Doc).
                 DefaultIfEmpty(0).
                 Average()
```

Not related notice:
 Use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. `And` is bitwise operator and always executes both parts of comparison. Where `AndAlso` will executes only first part if first part fails.

Actually you can remove `AndAlso` and uses two Where methods - which will be little bid more readable/understandable

```vb
Dim monthReference = Month(Date_Reference) - 1
Dim yearReference = Year(Date_Reference)

Dim avg = MyList.Where(Function(s) Month(s.Histo_Date) = monthReference).
                 Where(Function(s) Year(s.Histo_Date) = yearReference).
                 Select(Function(s) s.Nb_Doc).
                 DefaultIfEmpty(0).
                 Average()
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation very useful, but how can I've the same indentation for my Linq Query on VS 2010 ?

Comment: Should work in VS2010. Remember keep dot on the original line.

Comment: I accept your answer, for me is the more useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking if the where part is `Nothing` in your `Average` function:

```
MyList.Where(Function(s) Month(s.Histo_Date) = Month(Date_Reference) - 1 And Year(s.Histo_Date) = Year(Date_Reference)).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(s) If(s Is Nothing, 0, s.Nb_Doc))
```